# Rails Mailer Net::SMTPServerBusy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail

With my rails site, when I try to send mail through GMail, it works perfectly.  But when I try to send it through MandrillApp, it gives the following error (RController.create is where the deliver command is called):

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy in RController#create 
454 4.7.1 <recipient@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

Here's my config/environments/development.rb file:

```
 # ActionMailer Config
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
#   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
#   :port                 => 587,
#   :domain               => 'gmail.com',
#   :user_name            => 'sender@gmail.com',
#   :password             => 'password',
#   :authentication       => 'plain',
#   :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
:port      => 587,
:user_name => ENV["EMAIL"],
:password  => ENV["PASSWORD"]
}
```

As it is above, the code doesn't work - I don't get an email and no errors pop up.  If I switch to sending it from GMail, I get an email almost instantly.  I've never worked with Mandrill before, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up talking to a service rep from Mandrill, and it turns out that I was using the actual strings instead of the environment variables, so I just had to remove "ENV" from the config file.

I ended up going back and making environment variables for security's sake, but I just thought I'd throw that out there in case anyone else has the same problem and finds this question.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. You should accept your own answer. I had to do get rid of the `ENV` and the `[]` like `"EMAIL"`.

Comment: Can you clarify your solution?  I currently have this line in my smtp_settings - :password  => ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY'].  According to your solution, how should this line read?

Comment: If you are defining MANDRILL_API_KEY as a program variable, rather than an environment variable, then you just need: `password => MANDRILL_API_KEY`, instead of `password => ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY']`.  An environment variable is more secure, since your API key will be stored on your computer/server instead of in your site (basically, someone could get hold of your code, and still not be able to get your key), but a normal variable is easier to implement - depends how concerned you are with security (although, properly, you should do an environment variable).

Comment: after plenty of research I finally found your solution <3 :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at the following set up [Mandrill SMTP Integration](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-using-mandrill-s-smtp-integration-with-web-frameworks). Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help (I was missing the authentication line), but it doesn't get rid of the error.  When I try to send an email, I still get the Net::SMTPServerBusy error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if the ENV variables are set in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Heroku, you need to set the environment variables in the CLI.

cd to your working directory and...

```
heroku config:set MANDRILL_USERNAME='YOUR USERNAME'
heroku config:set MANDRILL_APIKEY="YOUR API KEY"
```

You can now access the environment variables. I know you're working with development.rb but this might save you a headache when you get to production.rb. Caused me a headache for a few hours with my application.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that your problem is caused by Phusion Passenger (hence in production). Passenger is notorious for not setting environment variables.

This [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79474/setting-environment-variables-for-phusion-passenger-applications) suggests 2 solutions : hardcoding values, or overriding the ruby wrapper used by Passenger.

I'd suggest a third option : expanding the environment variables during the deployment. It's pretty much a delayed hardcoding, but leaves your passwords out of your code.

You should execute this bit of bash right after your deploy :

```
mv config/environments/production.rb config/environments/production.before_sed.rb
env | sed 's/[\%]/\\&/g;s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/s%ENV\\[\\"\1\\"\\]%\2%/' > script/expand_env_vars.sed.script
cat config/environments/production.before_sed.rb | sed -f script/expand_env_vars.sed.script > config/environments/production.rb
```

Here is the equivalent Capistrano deploy task (lot of escaping ahead !) :

```
desc "Replace environment variables with hardcoded values in config files"
task :replace_env_vars, roles: :app do
    run "mv #{release_path}/config/environments/production.rb #{release_path}/config/environments/production.before_sed.rb"
    run 'env | sed \'s/[\%]/\\&/g;s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/s%ENV\\\[\\\"\1\\\"\\\]%\\\"\2\\\"%/\' > ' + "#{release_path}/script/expand_env_vars.sed.script"
    run "cat #{release_path}/config/environments/production.before_sed.rb | sed -f #{release_path}/script/expand_env_vars.sed.script > #{release_path}/config/environments/production.rb"
end

after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:replace_env_vars"
```

Still for Capistrano, you don't have the same environment variables set in the SSH session it uses to deploy (it doesn't execute .bashrc, /etc/profile ...). You have to re-export them in `~/.ssh/environment` and append the following option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

These last instructions were found [there](http://pretheory.wordpress.com/2008/02/12/capistrano-path-and-environment-variable-issues/). I've personally documented a bit further my issue on my [new blog](http://adriendp.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/expanding-environment-variables-in-the-rails-config-on-a-capistrano-deploy-for-a-passenger-app/).

Hope this can help fix some security issues for you :)