# Devise Forgot Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use Devise to handle the "Forgot Password" requests - when I click "Forgot Password," it takes me to the page to enter my email and click "Send me reset instructions." But when I submit my email, I get the following error:

```
NameError in Devise::PasswordsController#create
uninitialized constant User::Mailer
```

I'm not sure how to fix this or how to even get to the Devise controllers code, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to set up devise's "Forgot password" your set up in your environment/development.rb should look like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "smtp.xxxxx.co.uk",
                                         :user_name => "username",
                                         :password => "password",
                                         :authentication => "login" }
```

In regards to your other your other question: [SMTP Server Busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963795/rails-mailer-netsmtpserverbusy) I don't see why you are you mandrill in the first place.