# Error using Mandrill (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby through a project that breaks down Airbnb and lets you clone it in steps.  We just implemented Mandrill to handle email transaction and I ran into an error that I am unfamiliar with and google hasn't offered much either.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slLqj.png)

I am usually able to follow the error message but I'm pretty lost with this one.  Any Help is appreciated.

Reed

Comment: Looks like Smtp server is busy ^^. Problem on Mandrill side

Comment: Please go through this reference [Doc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963795/rails-mailer-netsmtpserverbusy)

Comment: I'd hope Mandrill support could help you with this.